# Htaccess does not redirect mobile users to domain.com/m

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My page can be accessed through *domain.com* or *www.domain.com*
I am trying to have a redirect for users on mobile devices to the *domain.com/m or* *www.domain.com/m*

However I am having difficulties to do this correctly. I have put this in my .htaccess on index.php of domain.com

How to do this correctly?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/http://www.domain.com/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: The user agent string won't just be 'android' or 'blackberry', it'll be something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1` so you'll need to check that the user agent *contains* one of those strings, not that it is equal to one of them.

Comment: RewriteCond uses regular expressions, if you find "Android" in that user agent string, it will match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipad" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipod" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iemobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "opera mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palmos" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "webos" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: What about my /www.domain.com/ and /m/ ?

Comment: You probably don't need the first line. Also, fixed my post, you should use ORs to manage the list better.

Comment: Go into the server log and paste the actual error. Saying there's an error doesn't help much.

Comment: Also, your Rewrite Rule is wrong, if I visit `site.com/m/somePage.html`, it's going to redirect to `site.com/m/` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Just find that fabulous Website. You got so many possibilities to make a mobile-redirect and they are updated frequently.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Hope it help you !

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file in [HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) actually handles this redirection nicely.

You should take a look either you are working with mobile or not or if you just want to redirect certain UA clients.

Comment: Thank  you but still does not redirect my Windows Phone 7.5

Comment: Try adding the following regexp `(windows\ phone\ (.*?)\d\.\d)` to detect any version of Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this is way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (iphone|ipod|android|symbian|windows\ phone|blackberry|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile)   [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

and for me, it is working like a charm.